# A function space satisfying $ |f(x) -f(y)| \le ||x|^\theta -|y|^\theta| $

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, vector-lattices, besov-space

Consider a class of function on the real line such that $$  |f(x) -f(y)| \le ||x|^\theta -|y|^\theta | $$
for a $\theta >0$.

Does this class of function space have a name 
When $  |f(x) -f(y)| \le |x-y|^\theta  $, it is the $\theta-Holder $ function space. My condition is a little bit stronger. I think it should have be considered somewhere. Can anyone provide any information about this class of function space? or some function spaces which satisfy this condition.

Comment: Note that $\phi(x,y)=||x|^\theta -|y|^\theta |$ is not a distance on the real line since $\phi(x,-x)=0$.